# Reading/writing permissions of cookie in subdir or parentdir

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cookies, session-cookies

Suppose a cookie is set to `/foo` using

```
Set-Cookie: mytoken=12345; Path="/foo"
```

Which of the following pages will be able to **read** and which will be able to **write/remove** this cookie?

```
/page.html
/foo/page.html 
/foo/bar/page.html
/baz/page.html
```

Comment: Anything parallel/above the specified directory will NOT see the cookie, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read/Write/Remove**:

```
/foo/page.html 
/foo/bar/page.html
```